# C# WPF Binding Get Reference To Source Row From Selected Item

Tags: .net, wpf, listview, binding

Binding a ListView:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DF.DocFieldEnum1rows, Mode=OneWay}".
```

`DF.DocFieldEnum1rows` is `List<DocFieldEnum1row>`.

Item template binding:

```
<Button  Content="{Binding Path=FieldEnum1Row.StrValue, Mode=OneWay}" 
    Click="Button_Click" />.
```

In the `Button_Click` I get access to the `Path=FieldEnum1Row.StrValue` value, but how can I  get access to the source `DocFieldEnum1row`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataContext` of your `Button` should be the instance of the row.

```
private void buttonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;

    var row = (YourRowType)b.DataContext;
}
```